# Unable to pass Asyncstorage data to Authorization header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

Thanks, for the replies below, this is the real issue I'm facing, I save a token to AsyncStorage to access it for authorization, but all effort seems abortive. this is the code below,

```
const storageGet = async () => {
    try {
         const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
         console.log("data", result);
         return result;
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
  }

  (async () => {
    try{
      const x = await storageGet()
      console.log("nowToken", x) // it returns the token

    }catch(err) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })();
```

it returns the token in variable x but I'm unable to pass it to that authorization below

```
export const setHeaders = () => {
    const header = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: // I need to pass the token here
        }
    }
    return header
}
```

Comment: `async` functions always return promises. To get access to the eventual value, either call `.then` on the promise, or put your code in an `async` function and `await` the promise.

Comment: It should be `var authToken = await storageGet()`, so you actually get the resolved value of the promise. This is assuming that you are not calling this in the top level. Otherwise `var authToken = storageGet().then(...)` will also work.

Comment: I'm still getting errors, if anybody can help me refractor the code above, I will be happy.

Comment: How do you set the token? Your `token` in storage might be null or undefined, so the issue could be with the `AsyncStorage.setItem` function. If it's an issue with the promise, what is the error after you tried the suggestions above? It's also a good idea to make your storage keys constants to avoid unwanted side effects

Comment: I'm able to solve that, help me review the edited code above